# On click jusmp between array elements JS to show and hide a div

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

all
 This code select a random element in the array that will hide/show a div It toggle it. 
The point is that I need that it always open a new one and hide the previous one with the same button. 
I have done that it shows a new one but  It doesn't hide the previous.
It is not mandatory to be random, but it needs to always open a new element and hide them .  I am a bit stuck

I would appreciate some clues around. 
Thanks a lot for ur attention

```
document.getElementById("rojo").addEventListener("click", show);
var secret =  ["h-ma-1","h-ma-2","h-ma-3" ];
var s = secret[RndInt(0, 2)];

function RndInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min+ 1) ) + min;}


function show (){

        for ( var i=0 ; i<=0 ; i++ ){
                if 
            (document.getElementById(s).style.display == "block")
                {
            document.getElementById(s).style.display = "none";
                }
                else 
                {
            document.getElementById(s).style.display = "block";
                }
        }


    }
```

Comment: `for ( var i=0 ; i<=0 ; i++ )` this will only execute once, since the `i<=0` condition will fail after `i++`.

Comment: Yeah, it is right! Sorry  I have another version.. but even if I add the length of the array it fails :D

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you with you task

```js
document.getElementById("rojo").addEventListener("click", show);
var secret = ["h-ma-1", "h-ma-2", "h-ma-3"];
var s = secret[RndInt(0, 2)];

const DEFAULT_VISIBILITY = 'block';

const mapToggle = {
  'block': 'none',
  'none': 'block'
};

function getCurrentVisibility(node) {
  return node.style.display;
}

function getElementFromId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function toggleVisibility(node) {
  node.style.display = mapToggle[getCurrentVisibility(node) ||  DEFAULT_VISIBILITY];
}

function toggle(ids) {
  ids.forEach((id) => {
    var node = getElementFromId(id);
    if (node) {
      toggleVisibility(node);
    }
  });
}

function RndInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


function show() {
  toggle(secret);
}
```

```html
<div id="h-ma-1">h-ma-1</div>

<div id="h-ma-2">h-ma-2</div>

<div id="h-ma-3">h-ma-3</div>

<button id="rojo">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Please click the Tidy button when you create snippets. Your indentation is all over the place.

Comment: Thanks a lot I ll check it out

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong with the original code and how you fixed it, not just post code.

Answer (score 0):

So far  this  has been helping me to solve my problem but it is not done by using the array itself. And so it might difficult to keep in maintenance
It is done by changing the name of the div directly by adding the last part of the name. 
I  just  put all the div in the css as diplay = none .

Thanks

document.getElementById("rojo").addEventListener("click", show);

```
function show (){

        for ( var i=-0 ; i<12 ; i++ ){
                s="h-ma-"+i;

        document.getElementById(s).style.display = "none";

        }
        document.getElementById("h-ma-"+Math.ceil(Math.random()*11)).style.display = "block";

                }
```